# Am I heading the right direction in designing web-based social games?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

For the last couple of days, I have been on a jQuery frenzy literally designing everything using this wonderful library. I am planning to design a web-based social game (for deployment on social networks like Facebook) from scratch and would like some pointers on understanding how to divide the tasks i.e. to what extent should jQuery be used. Following are my thoughts. Please let me know if I am heading in the right direction.

I am envisioning the game to be a simple multiplayer game where users can compete with each other and gain points (and the game is more like role-based or static rather than a dynamic mario style game). For this most of the points-logic and book keeping should be done on the server side using PHP and MySQL. For client side rendering, I am planning to use jQuery (and have no plans of taking the Flash route). So all the interactions will be handled on the client side using jQuery and the state will be saved on the server.

Now, this is a very naive process but I was wondering if there are any resources that explain the above in more detailed steps i.e. from the perspective of designing an actual game from a multiplayer perspective keeping scalability in mind. I don't need a very complex game... even a simple Q&A game will suffice to boost my understanding of how to actually use these languages to create a good enough game. Any suggestions? Also, is it recommended to use a gaming engine when doing the game in jQuery?

Comment: It really depends on exactly what type of game you want to make - if it's mainly text, images and form fields, jQuery will be great; if it's animation and custom user interaction you'll want to find something more powerful.

Comment: @Jakub Hampl: At my current stage of design, it is more of a logic based game rather than an animation driven game. Out of curiosity, could you expand on the more powerful topic you were mentioning?

Comment: I can guess @Jakub means Flash AS3, which is something more powerful with animation, interaction, etc.

Comment: I was meaning a dedicated gaming library - currently the Akihabara project seems nice (http://www.kesiev.com/akihabara/), though heavily retro oriented and impactjs will probably be awesome when it's done (http://impactjs.org/). Both support things like sound, sprite animation and manipulation, hit detection, keyboard input, etc.

Comment: @Jakub Hampl: You do have a lot of information in this domain :) Thank you very much for the pointers! If you know of any RPG-specific libraries, please let me know. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems possible.  It depends on the type of game, I'm making a 2D RPG.  Although the client is for Android, I've built the editor using jQuery.  There are existing game jQuery libraries you may want to look at.

Try to use the jQuery UI toolkit as much as possible.  They'll make your life much easier.  Specially things like Dialog.

How are you going to communicate with your server?  If you need something with good speed and low latency, use websockets.  (Though less browsers support it.)

Otherwise, you'll want to design your server side code in a REST style.  That way you can on the browser you can use $.ajax with it's simplicity.

I don't know much about PHP because I don't use it.  But if your game is not realtime you can certainly make something scalable with it.  I *think* Zynga uses PHP for their games.

All in all, I can definetly vouch for jQuery when it comes to this.  Specially if it's logic driven you can easily make a social game with it.

Also, this is optional.  Make your html pages use the jQuery UI theme classes wherever possible so that the pages look good with the jQuery widgets.

Check out the screenshots at the end of my blogpost here: http://developingthedream.blogspot.com/2010/10/player-map-making-in-browser.html

Answer (score 1):

jQuery shines when it comes to DOM manipulation and operations. As far as using it to power a scalable online multiplayer game...I don't know that it was built with that in mind.  You might want to look at [processingJS](http://processingjs.org/exhibition).